# iOS - Xcode Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

When I run my app and try to press button `DONE` I see:

```
Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.
```

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class DeveloperViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func cancelToPlayersViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
}

@IBAction func saveDeveloperDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){

    if let developerDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? DeveloperDetailsViewController{

    developers.append(developerDetailsViewController.developer) //Here Thread 1

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: developers.count-1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    }
}

var developers: [Developers] = developersData

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return developers.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DeveloperCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as! UITableViewCell

        let developer = developers [indexPath.row] as Developers
        cell.textLabel?.text = developer.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = developer.type
        return cell
}
```

How can I resolve my problem?
In another program all works.

Comment: And what is the done button connected to? How does it relate to the code you show?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: When you press done you go back to table view

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error!
But if DDPWNAGE doesn't ask what does error log say, didn't found it.
I forgot 1 ID.
And now all work